# Navigation bar for UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am new on iOS. Trying to implement a navigation bar for my `UIWebView`.

My `TableView` calls the webview when user clicks on any row. I load different local HTML files based on the index user clicked on. My webview is loading correctly but the problem is, I want to keep a navigation bar and `< back` button there, so that user can click it to come back to the tableview.

Here is the my `ProductTableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "ProductTableViewCell"


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell

    let product = products[indexPath.row]

    cell.name.text = product.name
    cell.generic.text = product.generic

    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let resultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("webView") as? WebViewController {
        presentViewController(resultController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //print(indexPath.row)
    clickedOn = indexPath.row
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController;
    //if clickedOn == 3{
        svc.fileName = "Ace-VetBolus"
    //}
}
```

And my `WebViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //print("got: "+self.fileName)

    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(self.fileName, withExtension:"html")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    web1.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Please help me to write `Swift` code for this.

Comment: did you embed navigation controller in WebViewController

Comment: No. I tried but webview doesn't get loaded or I maybe couldn't configure properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting the `WebViewController` on `ProductTableViewController`, and want to have Bar Buttons on Navigation bar, I would suggest you to embed `WebViewController` in `UINavigationController` in IB.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let navc = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController;
    let svc = navc.topViewController as! WebViewController;
    //if clickedOn == 3{
        svc.fileName = "Ace-VetBolus"
    //}
}
```

Will be the minor change in `prepareForSegue` method.

The back button on bar has to be added manually.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` with following one, it works for me.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if let resultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("webView") as? WebViewController {
            let navController : UINavigationController = UINavigationController (rootViewController: resultController)
            self.navigationController?.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        //print(indexPath.row)
        clickedOn = indexPath.row
    }
```